# Ajax and PHP, Undefined index: is_ajax

Tags: php, ajax

so I was trying to do some Ajax login and I have this code in my script. It's a javascript and when a form is clicked submit, it submits to login_p.php with the variables
email, password and is_ajax.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.login-button').click(function() {
            var action = $('#login-form').attr('action');
            var form_data = {
                email: $("#email").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                is_ajax: 1
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: form_data,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'success'){
                        document.location="index.php?authi";
                    } 
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the information in login_p.php

```
<?php    
    session_start();
    $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
    if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
    {
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        include('db.class.php');
        $db = new db();
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='" . $email . "'");
        $rows = $db->countRows($query);
        if($rows == 1) {
            $results = $db->getRows($query);
            foreach($results as $result) {
                extract($result);
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

but the error that I get is:

```
Undefined index: is_ajax
```

and I have no idea why. Everything seems to be working fine. Would appreciate if someone could tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined index` is a PHP **NOTICE**, not an error. You are getting it because you are attempting to access `$_REQUEST['is_ajax']`, but the index 'is_ajax' is not set in the `$_REQUEST` array.

You can either change your `error_reporting` settings in php.ini to exclude `E_NOTICE` or you can change your code to something more like:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax'])) {
    $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
    // ...
}
```

---

If you think you did pass in the `is_ajax` parameter, try doing `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what you're really getting.